# iOS MKMapView setCenterCoordinate does not honor the exact coordinate

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, centering, coordinate

I have the following code to center on the user's current location when the locate button is pressed:

```
- (void)locate
{
    if (self.curLocation) {
        [self.googleMapView setCenterCoordinate:self.curLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"setting center (%f,%f), but got (%f,%f)", self.curLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.curLocation.coordinate.longitude, self.googleMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, self.googleMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
    }
}
```

The output of the NSLog is "setting center (37.785834,-122.406417), but got (37.785826,-122.406406)"

Which means that setCenterCoordinate moved to an approximate coordinate instead of the one instructed. This is very inconvenient because when I implement the zoom level, zooming out at the same location then zooming back in (since setRegion changes the center coordinate as well) will move away from the old location. This is counter-intuitive and the Android platform API does not exhibit this erratic behavior.

Could someone explain why setCenterCoordinate does not go to the exact coordinate, and if possible, any way to make sure zooming out-and-in will have the same center. Thanks.

Comment: are you changing the frame of the MKMapView?

Comment: I don't think so... I stripped all the other mapview-related code and this should be the only thing left.

Answer (score 4):

You could save your original "good" center coordinate in an ivar, then use that each time you zoom in. That way it should always go back to where it started. I assume you're zooming in with a button or by calling a method.

The center coordinate doesn't seem to be reliable. It gets more reliable as you zoom in, but it never seems to be set to exactly what you ask. Even using the center coordinate returned by `regionThatFits:` won't give an exact match, which it should. You can use `-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` to experiment with this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0001f, 0.0001f);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {35.67106,139.764909};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};

    MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    NSLog(@"Fit Region %f %f", regionThatFits.center.latitude, regionThatFits.center.longitude);

    [self.mapView setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];
//  [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
//  [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:NO];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Center: %f %f", myMapView.region.center.latitude,myMapView.region.center.longitude);
}
```

Comment: So I should save (37.785826,-122.406406), the coordinate mapview actually centers on, instead of my asking coordinate, to ensure going back to where it started?

Comment: Yeah, save that as something like `CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate` and each time the map is zoomed, set it as the center coordinate (combined with whatever region you need to zoom the map).

Answer (score 0):

The final parameter in setCenterCoordinate is "animated". You're setting that to YES so it may take a second or so to get to the correct location. Since that happens on another thread the NSLog line happens before the map has reached the target coordinates. Either wait a moment or two before reading the center, or activate your NSLog statement via button on screen so you can be sure you do it after the map has stopped moving.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Still gives me (37.785826,-122.406406).

Comment: I've looks up those two coordinates and they seem to be less than 2m apart. Given the accuracy of the GPS built into the phone you might find that the movement is irrelevant to your app.

Comment: Hi Craig, the GPS is irrelevant to my problem here. I am explicitly asking the center to be set to a certain point (37.785834,-122.406417), but is not honored. The reason I _must_ fight this behavior is because when setCenterCoordinate drifts, zooming out (setRegion) on street X then later zooming back in will land me on a different street Y, though I never changed the center coordinate.